# Работа в много потоке с SerialPort c#

Tags: c#, wpf, task, serialport

проблема такая, пытаюсь сделать многопоточную обработку comPorts на устройстве
Использую async/await Task и под каждый порт создаю свой Task.
Делаю цикличный опрос каждого порта, но проблема в том что когда портов много что-то происходит с оборудование толи перестаёт отвечать или ещё что-то, по системной ошибке смог выяснить что проблема с драйверами или с тем что, устройство не отвечает, Windows уходит в синий экран и перезагружает пк.

По другого производителя с этими устройствами в многопоточном режиме работает корректно.

При этом паузы await Task.Delay повсюду как можно больше
Я пробовал запускать опрос портов в 1 поток всё работает корректно, перебрал уже весь код по косточкам, не могу понять причину.
Хочу сделать очередь для обращения к Serial Port, но не знаю как лучше это реализовать, возможно нужен класс где будет single Queue и какой-то метод который будет обрабатывать эту очередь и отправлять данные в ком-порт.
Но тогда получается узкое место и как после выполнения этой задачи вернуть её в тот же поток где её добавили в очередь, не понимаю.
Может кто-то предложит более красивый вариант?

Comment: _паузы await Task.Delay повсюду как можно больше_ - открою вам секрет: никаких пауз вообще не должно быть. Любые задержки для синхронизации чего-либо с чем-либо - это костыли, при чем страшные. _Может кто-то предложит более красивый вариант?_ - единственный красивый вариант здесь - Producer/Consumer. Больше не глядя в код, здесь сказать нечего.

Comment: Просто код лучше любого самого крутого рассказа о нем. Так же уточните, что за операционная система и версия дотнета. Вообще там космически сложного ничего нет, но обсуждение сферического кода в вакууме здесь ни к чему не приведет. Отредактируйте вопрос, покажите релевантный код.